# How do I correct send this post request in Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, beautifulsoup

`I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried adding a user agent as well as changing the end point of my request. What do I have to do to correct send the post request

```
headers = {
"User-Agent":
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)           Chrome/118.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"}

telefoongids_input = "https://www.detelefoongids.nl/api/search/index"
myObj2 = {"who":"John", "where": "Amsterdam", "page": 0}
b = requests.post(url=telefoongids_input, data="myObj2", headers=headers )
b1 = b.text
print(b1)
```

ive tried enter the code ^^ however I keep getting this response 400 response

Comment: The webpage at https://www.detelefoongids.nl/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
`ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED`

Comment: `data="myObj2"` You're sending the literal string "myObj2" instead of the **variable** named `myObj2`...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.detelefoongids.nl/api/search/index"

payload = {"page": 1, "where": "Amsterdam", "who": "John"}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.get("https://www.detelefoongids.nl/")
    s.headers.update({"x-xsrf-token": s.cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"]})
    data = s.post(url, json=payload).json()
    print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "totalItems": 8,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "161862750",
            "firstname": "P",
            "familyname": "John",

...
```